# Open Source Simple Speech Recognition in C++ in Windows

Tags: c++, open-source, voice-recognition

I was wondering, are there any basic speech recognition tools out there? I just want something that can distinguish the difference between "yes" and "no" and is reasonably simple to implement. Most of the stuff out there seems to make you start from scratch, and I'm looking for something more high level.

Thanks!

Comment: "Simple Speech Recognition" seems like a contradiction in terms.

Comment: It does. But I'd like to start as simple as simple goes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Sphinx3 & PocketSphinx](http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/) are written in C, so it shouldn't be too hard wrap it for C++. It's still an active project too, which is good.

Comment: +1 Looks interesting, will definitely look into it.

Answer (score 4):

You might also look at Julius, which is similarly an open source speech recognizer: http://julius.sourceforge.jp/en_index.php